# Date Comparison in MYSQL format d-m-Y

Tags: mysql

Good Day!

My date in MYSQL is in d-m-Y format but column is of vachar datatype.
When I try below query, it returns correct values

```
select * from inspection where date=date_format(str_to_date('02-10-2022', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

But when I compare two dates, it returns wrong values like all dates of all months it compares i.e. 02-09-2022, 02-10-2022 even if I need only for 02-10-2022 etc

```
select * from inspection where date between date_format(str_to_date('01-10-2022', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') and date_format(str_to_date('02-10-2022', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

I basically want to search data between two dates, which are of varchar data type but are stored in column as d-m-Y
Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and the expected result would help to understand your issue.

Comment: Why are you using vachar to store date use correct format https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: You should review what date_format does - 'DATE_FORMAT() returns a string with a character set and collation given by character_set_connection and collation_connection ' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for date comparison puposes use str_to_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of

```
date_format(str_to_date('02-10-2022', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

is '02-10-2022'. `str_to_date()` is converting your string to a propper date. And then `date_format()` converts the resulting date to the original string. At the end this piece of code is doing nothing, but is doing it in a quite complex way. If you need an equality comparison you can just use

```
where date = '02-10-2022'
```

But when you need a range check, you will need to convert the column to a sortable format - The default is *YYYY-MM-DD* or `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Here you can use `str_to_date()`:

```
select *
from inspection
where str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
  between str_to_date('01-10-2022', '%d-%m-%Y')
      and str_to_date('02-10-2022', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

or simpler:

```
where str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y') between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-02'
```

Better yet, fix your data and store dates in a `DATE` type column. Your question here is reason enough for that. The sooner you do that, the more time you will save in the future. And you will be able to use indexes for range conditions or for sorting. Using `str_to_date()` you loose that ability.